# Get cryptocurrency twitter, website, and markets from coinmarketcap.com api

Tags: api, twitter, screen-scraping

I am trying to get the twitter name, website, and markets for any cryptocurrency listed on coinmarketcap.

For example:
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin shows all of the data that I need but how would I parse the data listed on that page to get the twitter name and website associated with bitcoin?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to parse the data on that page if you are trying to use it in an application. If you are doing it for a one time data collection then maybe that is OK. There is absolutely no guarantee that the format will remain consistent or that the information will even be there tomorrow.

You should try to find an API that gives you the information that you are looking for. An API is a contract that is expected to be honored and therefore is reliable. A quick look at CoinMarketCap's API doesn't appear to have the info you are looking for but maybe another one exists that does.

If you were to parse the HTML you could write a regex for the specific thing you are looking for. For example if you want to get the website you could write a regex that would pick up the pattern:

```
<a href="([^"]+)" target="_blank">Website</a>
```

the capture group ([^"]+) is the website in this example. You could do something like that for every element you want to get.